# get every x numbers between two values

Tags: php, range

Is it possible to get every number divisible by **25000** between **2** values in php.  For example, I am given the *Min* price of **191000** and the *Max* price of **432000**.  I know that I can do this using `range()` if I have a predefined array of the values but I am sure there is a better way to do it.  Basically so the values returned are :

```
191000
200000
225000
...
425000
432000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop (or @mschuett uses a `foreach` on a `range()`) and then the modulus operator (`%`) to see if the number is divisible by 25,000:

```
$numbers = array();
for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    if($i % $divisible === 0) $numbers[] = $i;
}
print_r($numbers);
```

---

Or you can find out the first number divisible by 25,000 and then use a `for` loop that increments by 25,000:

```
$base = ceil($min / $divisible) * $divisible;
for($i = $base; $i <= $max; $i += $divisible) {
    $numbers[] = $i;
}
print_r($numbers);
```

---

Obviously in both examples `$min`, `$max`, and `$divisible` need to be defined. Both examples output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200000
    [1] => 225000
    [2] => 250000
    ...
    [9] => 425000
)
```

Comment: Ahh how dumb I feel now. Lol. Thanks for the answer! I will accept as soon as it will let me.

Comment: @JeffThomas I added a second example. It is not as obvious as the initial answer, but it will be slightly more efficient because it only has to do one mathematical operation and loops through a much smaller set of numbers. Let me know if you need an explanation.

Comment: @Sam +1 for the second example, way more efficient than the first

Comment: Didn't realize you wanted the min/max. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(range(min, max) as $num){
    if($num % 25000 == 0){
        echo $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good use of `range()`, didn't think of it even though it was in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping through 100,000's of times, you could combine a for loop with some rounding

```
$arr = [];
for($i = 191000; $i <= 432000; $i++) {
    $i = ceil($i / 25000) * 25000;
    if ($i > 432000) {
        break;
    }
    $arr[] = $i;
}
```

Comment: Interesting logic, kind of an combination of my two examples. +1